# R loading Files from Folder Mac Catalina OS

Tags: r, macos

In version R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) -- "Action of the Toes",on Mac Catalina OS.
I'm trying to load files from folder, code bellow, however it does not do it at the first time, and I need to run it twice to get the files loaded.
What could be happening? How could be solved?

```
remove(list=ls())
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(easycsv)
theDir=easycsv::choose_dir()
thePath=setwd(theDir)
current.list <- list.files(path = thePath, pattern =".tif$", full.names=TRUE)
```

Comment: There is no need to set the working directory. What does `current.list <- list.files(path = theDir, pattern =".tif$", full.names=TRUE)` give, after removing the line `thePath=setwd(theDir)`?

Comment: If I remove the line thePath=setwd(theDir) it does not allow me to choose files only folders and when choosing one there is an error: Error in list.files(path = thePath, pattern = ".tif$", full.names = TRUE) : 
  object 'thePath' not found

Comment: If you executed my suggestions correctly, `thePath` would not be used, so this error cannot occur.

Comment: Yes, is correct after executing your suggestion correctly it works well: remove(list=ls())
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(easycsv)
theDir=easycsv::choose_dir()
current.list <- list.files(path = theDir, pattern =".tif$", full.names=TRUE)